# USA J1-visa: apply in country different form passport nationality

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas, embassies

I need to apply for the J1-visa, and I have an Italian passport. I do not yet have the DS-2019 (so I cannot complete the DS-160 yet).

**Question:**
Can I apply for the visa at a USA embassy in United Kingdom?

I am confused because:

i) I see I have to choose an embassy at the very first step for the DS-160 (https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/),

ii) but the phrasing in **Completing the DS-160** here:

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/ds-160-faqs.html

makes me think that once the DS-160 is completed I can apply to any embassy in any country for the interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. You can apply for a US nonimmigrant visa to a US embassy/consulate in almost any country (there are a few rare exceptions, such as Japan, but the UK isn't one of them).